# Server is started, application is running but not accessible in browser

Tags: linux, jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss

My client has provided an `ip is 192.168.1.205` of linux machine on which JBoss server & mySql db are installed and accessible after VPN connection only.

**Previous Status Summary**

```
VPN connected ...
Deployed EAR application to server <JBOSS_HOME>/server/default/deploy/
Start Server e.g. 
   #<JBOSS_HOME>/bin:> ./run.sh -b 192.168.1.205 
Application access in browser : success
```

Now client has provided a `public IP (119.55.15.165)` and says application can be accessed without VPN connection. I did the same as above but neither application is accessible via public ip nor `@192.168.1.205` after vpn connection while i can see the process id and server log file which proves that JBOss is started and application is running.

As i tried to start application service with following command but deployment got failure

```
 #<JBOSS_HOME>/bin:> ./run.sh -b 119.55.15.165
  Status: Deployment Failure
 #<JBOSS_HOME>/bin:> ./run.sh -b 192.168.1.205
 Status: Deployment Success, Server started, Appl'n running but not accessible in browser
```

Please help me out on this.